# Not able to pass base url for different test build environment in ember cli

Tags: ember-cli

I am trying to set different base url for development test and stage test environments in ember cli.
Test environment name is always same (which is "test") irrespective of environment passed in command line.

Am looking for some thing like this. Please let me know if anyone have any solution.Thanks in advance

```
if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.baseURL = '/';
  }

  if (environment === 'test') {
    if (ENV PASSED === 'stage')
    ENV.baseURL = '/stage'; 
else
ENV.baseURL = '/';
  }

  if (environment === 'stage') {
    ENV.baseURL = '/stage'; 
  }
```

Comment: I didn't see any problem with this setup... What was the problem with this?

Comment: The issue is ENV PASSED is always coming as test inspie of the env being passed in command line. Ember CLI first time runs the build with the env passed in command line and second time it re run by automatically considering the env as test . I want to pass further categorization in the test run so that i can decide different base urls for diff test env.

Comment: you can have if (ENV.PASSED === 'stage') not ENV PASSED

Comment: I just put "ENV PASSED" as like a comment. Are you saying that ENV.PASSED will return stage if stage is sent in command line of environment? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/environment.js`, do something like this:

```
if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/';
} 
if (environment === 'test') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/';
}
if (environment === 'stage') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/stage';
} 
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.baseURL = '/';
}
```

Then to use the ENV on stage environment, invoke the ember-cli like so:

```
ember server --environment=stage
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Though I need environment specific base url inside test if condition as a nested if .Like below `code` if (environment === 'test') {
  if (environment === 'stage' ) ENV.baseURL = '/stage'; else ENV.baseURL = '/'
} `code`